# React Hooks with typescript: Property 'data' does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have an error that makes no sense, I am typing the value of my state with hooks, but he says the error is not the same type.

Already tried with empty array and even array with some data and always error is the same.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'config/styles';
import Bed from './Bed';

interface DataTypes {
  date: string;
  value: number;
}

function Beds(): JSX.Element {
  const { data, setData } = useState<DataTypes[]>([]);

  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        {data.map((d, i) => (
          <Col key={i} sm={16.666} lg={10}>
            <Bed {...d} />
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </>
  );
}

export default Beds;
```

Erro this:

```
TypeScript error in /Users/keven/Documents/carenet/orquestra-frontend/src/Beds/index.tsx(11,11):
Property 'data' does not exist on type '[DataTypes[], Dispatch<SetStateAction<DataTypes[]>>]'
```

Comment: Change brackets: `const [ data, setData ] = ...` 

Comment: Ooooomg :( haha thanks, sorry!

Answer (score 15):

you should use const [ data, setData ] instead of const { data, setData }

Comment: I cannot believe, what a silly mistake I had, thanks by the way.

Answer (score 7):

It should be an array, not an object:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<DataTypes[]>([]);
```

You have this indication in the error message:

```
type '[DataTypes[], Dispatch<SetStateAction<DataTypes[]>>]'
```

Comment: The error is always the same regardless of type.

Property 'data' does not exist on type '[[], Dispatch<SetStateAction<[]>>]'.