# Improper return type with custom hook from useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following generic custom hook made with typescript:

```
import { useState } from "react"

export const useForm = <T>(initialValues: T) => {
    const[values, setValues] = useState<T>(initialValues)
    return [
        values,
        (        
        e: { target: HTMLInputElement}) => {
            setValues({
                ...values,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            })
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I'm trying to use it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from './useForm';

type FormValues = {
  email: string,
  password: string
}

const App : React.FC = () => {
  const initialValues: FormValues = {email: "", password: ""}
  const [values, handleChanges] = useForm<FormValues>(initialValues);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="email" value={(values.email} onChange={e => handleChanges}/>
      <input 
        type="password"
        name="password"
        value={values.password}
        onChange={e => handleChanges}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My problem is around

```
values.email
```

and

```
values.password
```

The error message is:

> Property 'email' does not exist on type 'FormValues | ((e: { target: HTMLInputElement; }) => void)'.
>     Property 'email' does not exist on type '(e: { target: HTMLInputElement; })
>
> Property 'password' does not exist on type 'FormValues | ((e: { target: HTMLInputElement; }) => void)'.
>     Property 'password' does not exist on type '(e: { target: HTMLInputElement; })

If values is an unioun between FormValues and another value shouldn't I be able to access **email** and **password** from it?

Comment: your code has `onChange={e => handleChanges}` . that's a typo right? you mean `onChange={handleChanges}` ?

Comment: yes @azium, I've made some changes here and now I get a similar problem with handleChanges. Type 'FormValues | ((e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void)' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58140242/react-hooks-with-typescript-property-data-does-not-exist-on-type this guy has a similar problem, but its not solved there

Answer (score 2):

The problem is my return type. It seems I have to explicitly put it on the code signature.

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { ChangeEvent } from "react"

function useForm<T>(
    initialState: T,
  ): [T, (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void] {
    const [values, setValues] = useState<T>(initialState);

    function handleChange(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
      setValues({
        ...values,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
    }

    return [values, handleChange];
  }

  export default useForm;
```